# Convert Hebrew with vowels to extended ascii?

Tags: vb.net, unicode, ascii, hebrew

I have Hebrew text that contains vowels so it is in some kind Unicode which I'm not familiar with. I don't want the vowels and I would like to convert it to Hebrew using extended ascii where I believe Hebrew starts at ASCII 128. 
How can I do this? I am vb.net but not much else. 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried your best friend? (of course I mean google)
Take a look at **[this result](http://blog.shaftek.org/2005/06/03/removing-vowels-from-hebrew-unicode-text/)** i've got from searching "how to strip hebrew vowels from a unicode string?" in google.

### edit

try this:

```
Public Function StripHebewVowels(HebrewWithVowels As String) As String
    Return New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[\u0591-\u05C7]").Replace(HebrewWithVowels, "")
End Function
```

Comment: I did. But I only know vb.net and the code you pointed me to is something else. I am not able to duplicate it in vb.et